# pasting similar var names based on shared root into another var

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I'd like to paste similar var names found in one data frame (df1) into a var (df2$varconsistsof) in another data frame, if the root-name for the similarly named vars in the first data frame are present in a var (df2$var) in the second data frame.

Thanks for any help!

```
# Starting point 
df1 <- data.frame(abc_book_E1_C1=c(1:5),abc_book_E1_C2=c(1:5),abc_book_E1_C3=c(1:5),def_book_E1_C1=c(1:5),abc_toy_E1_R1=c(1:5),abc_toy_E1_R2=c(1:5)) 
df2 <- data.frame(var=c("abc_book","abc_toy"),varconsistsof=c(NA,NA))

# Goal
dfgoal <- data.frame(var=c("abc_book","abc_toy"),varconsistsof=c("abc_book_E1_C1,abc_book_E1_C2,abc_book_E1_C3","abc_toy_E1_R1,abc_toy_E1_R2"))

# Attempts
df2$varorigin <- grep(df2$var,names(df),value=TRUE) 
df2$varorigin <-  apply(df1, 1, function(df2$var) grep(df2$var,names(df),value=TRUE))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
df2$varconsistsof = lapply(df2$var, function(x){colnames(df1)[grepl(x,colnames(df1))]})
```

Output:

```
       var                                  varconsistsof
1 abc_book abc_book_E1_C1, abc_book_E1_C2, abc_book_E1_C3
2  abc_toy                   abc_toy_E1_R1, abc_toy_E1_R2
```

Note that now `str(df2)` returns

```
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ var          : Factor w/ 2 levels "abc_book","abc_toy": 1 2
 $ varconsistsof:List of 2
  ..$ : chr  "abc_book_E1_C1" "abc_book_E1_C2" "abc_book_E1_C3"
  ..$ : chr  "abc_toy_E1_R1" "abc_toy_E1_R2"
```

and to make the second column into simple strings, you could use `sapply` and wrap the statement in `paste` with parameter `collapse=',`, so:

```
df2$varconsistsof = sapply(df2$var, function(x){
            paste(colnames(df1)[grepl(x,colnames(df1))],collapse=',')})
```

and now `str(df2)` returns

```
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ var          : Factor w/ 2 levels "abc_book","abc_toy": 1 2
 $ varconsistsof: chr  "abc_book_E1_C1,abc_book_E1_C2,abc_book_E1_C3" "abc_toy_E1_R1,abc_toy_E1_R2"
```

Hope this helps!